# Healthcheck of mysql using sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, health-monitoring

I am looking for a lightweight healthcheck using sqlalchemy engine when connected to mysql. Is there a method available at the pool level to check whether the all the connections in the pool all are valid?